# Deploy custom newform for custom list using wsp for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, sandbox-solution, elements-xml

I have a custom list which inherits 2 custom content types. Each content type contains around 50 odd fields. I have to customize the layout of the form and integrate jquery for the newform and editform and associate the NewForm of the Content type to this customized NewForm.

I need to deploy this newly customized form using WSP. Hence I cannot use SharePoint Designer for customizing the layouts of the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx. Environment to be deployed on is SharePoint Online hence Application Pages are out of question.

What I am trying to do is create new custom MyNewForm.aspx for the list where I can realign the fields as per expectations in the DataFormWebPart and then copy the contents from the page , paste it in MyNewForm1.aspx which is bundled in the module in the WSP Solution package.

The page is deployed but the webpart is throwing error of not well formed XML.
We can add DataFormWebPart to the elements.xml as well of the MyNewForm1.aspx which can add the webpart to the page. However, I am unable to create the Webpart tag which needs to be entered in element.xml.

I tried to create the same by exporting the webpart which was created with the help of sharepoint designer but it is giving me error.

Please help.